# div layout full height without vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a layout with a menu on the left and a main content area but the height is not working correctly.

Here is the demo with the [code](http://fiddle.jshell.net/oterox/3dshd/show/light/) y this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/3dshd/)

the html is:

```
<nav>
    <h2>logo</h2>
    <ul id="steps">
        <li><a href="">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="">four</a></li>
        <li><a href="">five</a></li>
        <li><a href="">six</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>more links</p>
    <p>more links</p>
    <p>more links</p>
</nav>

<div id="main-container" class="clearfix">

    <div id="main-header">
        <p>lorem ipsum</p>
    </div>

    <div id="main-area">

        <section class="step-1">

            <div class="box" data-panel="panel-option1">
                <a href="#">option1</a>
            </div>
            <div class="box" data-panel="panel-option2">
                <a href="#">option2</a>
            </div>
            <div class="box" data-panel="panel-option3">
                <a href="#">option3</a>
            </div>
            <div class="box" data-panel="panel-option4">
                <a href="#">option4</a>
            </div>

        </section>

        <section class="step-2">

        </section>

        <section class="step-3">

        </section>

        <section class="step-4">

        </section>

        <section class="step-5 ">

        </section>

        <section class="step-6">

        </section>


    </div>

</div>
```

the css is:

```
html,body { height: 100%; }
nav {
    float: left;
    /*display: none;*/
    background-color: #112943;
    width: 324px;
    height: 100%;
}
#main-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
#main-header {
    height: 160px;
    line-height: 160px;
    background-color: #005C85;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}
#main-area {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
#main-area section {
    display: none;
}
#main-area section:first-child {
    display: block;
}

.step-1 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.step-1 > div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.step-1 > div:first-child {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #DDD;
}

.step-1 > div:nth-child(2) {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    background: #CCC;
}

.step-1 > div:nth-child(3) {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    background: #72CCA7;
}

.step-1 > div:nth-child(4) {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: #10A296;
}
```

The main problem is the height, the nav doesn't have a full height.

The "section" area with the 4 boxes should fit the width and height and show/hide the section related to the nav option.

The page don't have vertical scroll, all the divs should fit the browser height

Maybe should i use another approach?

Comment: Have you tried clearing your floats?

Comment: not sure what should i float...

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, percentage doesn't work well so try using 'vh'. Use the value '100vh' for the nav.

```
nav{
height: 100vh;
}
```

It'll take the full size of the parent element which in this case is the browser.

If that doesn't work, then try the value 'inherit'.

```
nav{
height: inherit;
}
```

It works at times.